# How to propedit svn:externals in Windows7-cmd.exe?

Tags: svn, vim, cmd, windows-7, svn-externals

In linux, we can use the following command to edit `svn:externals`

```sh
EXPORT SVN_EDITOR=vim
svn propedit svn:externals ./
```

but `vim` is no support in `Windows7-cmd.exe`, how can i edit `svn:externals` in `Windows7-cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously:

`>svn propedit svn:externals ./`

will open default text-editor (Notepad) with temp-file for editing content-property, which after saving edits will be (TBT) transferred to object

Comment: thanks for your enlighten, this command need to set **SVN_EDITOR** first, in **cmd** use `set SVN_EDITOR=notepad`. or use the full command `svn pe svn:externals ./ --editor-cmd "notepad"`. otherwise `--editor-cmd "code -wn"` edit by **vscode**, `--editor-cmd "subl -wn"` edit by **sublime**. **vscode**, **sublime** or other editor need in you **PATH**.